# Warning during geometry optimization via Gaussian

Tags: theoretical-chemistry, software, molecular-structure, density-functional-theory

I have some recurrent problem with my DFT calculations [functional: hseh1pbe; basis:6-31+g(d,p), object: porphyrin derivative]. During the MO setting I get:

**** Warning!!: The largest alpha MO coefficient is  ***D+03

**** Warning!!: The smallest alpha delta epsilon is  ***D-01

I did some first-step research over the internet: the only considerable suggestion I found was to decrease the basis since some MOs got linear-dependent. I already decreased it from 6-311++g(d,p) so I assume that it didn't help much. Moreover, simplifying the basis set would mean increase in inaccuracy, right?

Did someone meet and solve this issue before?

Comment: For HD & DFT calculations a near-linear-dependency in a basis is usually not a problem, so you can ignore it. For post-HF treatments this might be an issue. [Details](http://www.ccl.net/chemistry/resources/messages/2002/04/23.005-dir/).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The link you gave it is what I mentioned. I still feel a bit awkward about those warnings.

Comment: First, are you sure you actually need diffuse functions (*)? Secondly, try Ahlrichs basis sets instead of Pople ones, say, Def2SVP instead of 6-31g(d,p) or Def2TZVP instead of 6-311g(d,p).

Comment: As for diffuse functions, no, I am not sure. I would think that it is good to include them for higher accuracy.
It's nice that you mentioned about Ahlrich's basis sets: I initially started with DGTZVP (in Gaussian) but the same problem occurred so then I started to minimize the basis set.